# Public university refuses to support ERC application

Tags: funding, europe

I'm from university from Central and Eastern Europe (btw. underrepresented in ERC). I contributed to the research proposal of my colleague for ERC starting grant. However, within internal review process at university level, representatives decided not to support the grant application and in addition they forbidden to apply even with another host institution with arguments

1. that the application may damage reputation of university
2. and may compete for funding with another "more preferred" team at university.
3. the outcome of the possible evaluation of the proposal may prevent application in next calls.

(Btw. the topic of research is mathematics and computational biology. No experiments on animals or humans or other possibly disputable ethic issues are involved :-) )

I've found in some ERC guides that there are restriction for unsuccessful applicants - thus point 3) is relevant.
But are points 1) or 2) relevant? Are there any "quota" for host institution. Is host institution restricted if application evaluation outcome is "B" or "C" or worse like "breach of research integrity"?

PI now do not expect funding from ERC, as success rate is only 12% and almost no support were given by university to improve proposal further. But is it worth to try to apply with support of another host institution (small spin-off company) just to get feedback from review panel?

Comment: In my institution, every holder of a tenure track is *required* to apply for an ERC grant. Therefore, I am surprised that one should not do this. Of course, a lot of effort is put into these applications. Maybe a really bad proposal may damage the reputation.

Comment: Most probably 2 is the real reason.  1 and 3 might just be excuses.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist This does not make sense. We had the very same PI get two grants in the same application round - as coordinator! If the applications are good, chances are there. Maybe the application is not written well?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs maybe application is not written well, but we do not know. The feedback we got so far criticize formalities not the topic.

Comment: Are the formalities essential to be fixed? Can you fix and resubmit to your local peer-review?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Sure, but the PI who got two grants probably did not submit two grants proposing the same project.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Did OP say that they competed on the same project? That's a bad idea anyway - you should have enough diversification in one institution to either propose different grants in different groups or to work together. No funding agency likes funding two competing proposals from the same institution.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs No, the OP would not know.  Item 2 implies that the two applications are excessively similar.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist No, 2. does not imply that. It may be the perception of the department that two proposals from the same department would compete for funds (independently of topic).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs My interpretation assumes the university is right.  Your interpretation assumes the university is wrong.  I see no point in further discussion.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I do not assume anything ("It *may* be..."). There is not enough information either way and OP should try to clarify that if they can.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs formalities cannot be met - participation on some workshops and events 6 months ago. We fixed some other formalities and decided to submit with another host institution (not university).

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist We do not know competitors on the same subject with same institution - or they do not publish in journals or conferences :-) Probably another proposal come from same department and met all internal criteria, but we do not have such information.